# Append the list of dictnary

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

I am writing a Python program with restart capabilities. I wanted to store the state of the program execution in a JSON format, so that during re-start it could query the Json and restart from the failed point.

JSON will be something like this:

```
{
    "job_name": xxxxx,
    "job_start_time": xxxxx,
    "site": xxxxxx,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": <unique id to look-up on restart>
            "task_start_time": 
            "task_end_time":
            "runtime":
            "successful": <true or false>
            "error_message":<if successful is false>
        }
    ]   
}
```

When a stage completes successfully, it appends a task dict to the list of tasks.

My question is how to append the task dictionary, while the entire python object remains.

Is it possible in JSON?

Comment: Your question's a bit broad. Which of these do you need help with: (1) reading json into Python, (2) adding a task to json file, (3) exporting json to a file? It helps if you have some code to share so we know which of these you need help with.

Comment: are you trying to run an aws-glue job using aws-step functions?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how to append the task dictionary, while the entire python object remains.

You can use the `update` method of dictionaries to modify the object. Here is an example:

```
d = {'inventory': [{'Color': 'Brown', 'Model': 'Camry', 'Year': 2018},
               {'Model': 'Corolla', 'Year': 2017}],
     'name': 'Toyota'}

d['inventory'][0].update({'Doors': 4})
print(d)
{'inventory': [{'Color': 'Brown', 'Doors': 4, 'Model': 'Camry', 'Year': 2018},
               {'Model': 'Corolla', 'Year': 2017}],
 'name': 'Toyota'}
```

Comment: When changing only one property, I'd prefer `d['inventory'][0]['Doors'] = 4` which is much more readable imo.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters in input json to the next job which is going to be the output from the current job. For ex:-

```
{
    "job_name": xxxxx_2,
    "job_start_time": xxxxx,
    "site": xxxxxx,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": <unique id to look-up on restart>
            "task_start_time": 
            "task_end_time":
            "runtime":
            "successful": <true or false>
            "error_message":<if successful is false>,
            "parameters":{
             "--Dict":{dict_values}
}
        }
    ]   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a dictionary? If so...

```
dictionary["tasks"].append(whatever)
```